# Question on calling a method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Beautiful sunny day today! However, I can't enjoy it because I've been trying to call a dynamic method in Mono for 2 days :-(

The Story:

I'm trying to call it within a class called 'Template'. Basically I would love it if I could pass a string to Template and have it run that method, which is defined within the Template class. The template class looks like this so far..

```
namespace Mash
{
    public class Template
    {
        public Template(string methodToCall)
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();
            object ob = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            object[] arguments = new object[52];
            type.InvokeMember(methodToCall,
                          BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                          null,
                          ob,
                          arguments);
        }
        public void methodIWantToCall()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm running the Method!");
        }
    }
}
```

No errors are received during compile time. Once I run it, however, I get

> 'Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() of Mash.Template'.'

I think it is failing here:

```
object ob = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did some edits. 1, you should know that you are doing reflection now, so basic rules must be followed (the answers provided are very helpful if you take a look carefully). 2, I don't think Microsoft .NET will not give you the same exception, so Mono tag is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need another instance of Template if the method you want to call is in the same class.You can use *this*

```
    public class Template
    {        
        public Template(string methodToCall)
        {
              this.GetType().InvokeMember(methodToCall,
                          BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                          null,
                          this,
                          null);

        }
        public void methodIWantToCall()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm running the Method!");
        }
   }
```

I tested it with:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Template m = new Template("methodIWantToCall");
        Console.ReadKey(true);

    }
 }
```

Comment: That works a treat, Paolo.. thank you for pointing that out, and thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `Activator.CreateInstance` is the type of the class, and then follows the argument of the constructor of the type.

You're trying to create an instance of the `Template` class using no parameter for the constructor. But there isn't a constructor with no parameter.

Try adding a constructor into your `Template` class, which takes no parameters:

```
public class Template
{
    //......
    public Template()
    {
    }
}
```